# how to solve slow p2p connection on turnserver using webrtc?

Tags: sockets, websocket, webrtc, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I've created the video Call App for using webrtc and also using turn server for p2p connection,

**Sometimes TurnServer not working properly**

***in a P2P connection,
User A Wants to connect the UserB, and the socket Server received the data, but***

```
UserB Video Doesn't show by UserA &&

UserA Video Doesn't show by UserB
```

*I refer to creating turn server using coturn*

https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/turn-server/

how to resolve it?
Thanks